# How to know archaeologist badge status

Tags: discussion

What is my archaeologist badge status.Do I have privileges to know this? 
What no of edits of mine in inactive for 6 months

Answer (score 1):

You can see your progress towards many badges using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer.](https://data.stackexchange.com/) Specifically, there's a good [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/69607/what-is-my-archaeologist-badge-progress) that tells you how many posts you've edited that were inactive for 6 months (and therefore eligible for the Archaeologist badge).